# Find repeated string after specified location in a file using python

Tags: python, regex

text file contains

```
paragraph 1: 
01 internet 1
02 intranet 2
paragraph 2: 
03 internet 1
04 intranet 2
paragraph 3: 
05 internet 1
06 intranet 2
paragraph 4: 
07 internet 1
08 intranet 2
```

I wanted to find intranet 2  in paragraph 2 using python.

This is what I have so far:

```
file = open( "c:\file.txt", "r" ).readlines()
var = raw_input("enter the value")
var1 = "paragraph 1:"
for line in file:
  if re.search(var1, line,re.IGNORECASE):
    print re.search(var, line,re.IGNORECASE)
    print "found", line
    count=line for line in file:
      if re.search(var, line,re.IGNORECASE):
        print "value=", line
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And, what exactly is the criteria for "after specified location"?

Comment: ok 

file = open( "c:\file.txt", "r" ).readlines()
var=raw_input("enter the value")
var1="paragraph 1:"
for line in file:
    if re.search(var1,line,re.IGNORECASE):
        print re.search(var,line,re.IGNORECASE)
        print "found",line
        count=line
        for line in file:
            if re.search(var,line,re.IGNORECASE):
                print "value=",line

Comment: When you say `find intranet 2 in paragraph 2`, what do you mean? You want to find out where in the file that location is? What the text is of the line at that position? What more is in the line if it `intranet 2` is just a marker? If `intranet 2` is in that section of the file at all? Does it have to be in the `paragraph 2` section or will any later section also be fine?

Comment: actually my aim is to find particular string paragraph section in a file not all intranet 2 string

Comment: It'd help if you put your attempted code into your question - it's not clear when placed in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want to search in the specified section this should work:

```
def find(file, paragrapgh_number, search_string):
    paragraph = 'paragraph {}'.format(paragrapgh_number)
    for line in file:
        if line.find(paragraph) >= 0:
            break
    for line in file:
        if line.find(search_string) >=0:
            print('Found:', line)
        elif line.find('paragraph') >= 0:
            print('Not found')
            return

with open( "./test.txt", "r" ) as file:
    find(file, 2, 'intranet 2')

>>>Found: 04 intranet 2
```

If the string is not found in the specified section it will show

```
>>>Not Found
```